# Future perfect continuous with the past reference

Tags: future-perfect

I came across this dialogue:

> A: I don't know anyone who saw the eclipse of the moon last night.
> B: I suppose most people will have been watching the Eurovision Song Contest on TV when it happened.

I don't understand why the future perfect continuous (**will have been watching**) is used to explain something happened in the **past**. Please tell me that this is a valid example and I am just missing something here. :)

I know that the future perfect or future perfect continuous can be used to tell something about the present. There are many examples I have seen. But I have not found anything how it can be used to tell something about the past event. Like in my example above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["No chance of finding him sober now; he will have been drinking all day."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7497/no-chance-of-finding-him-sober-now-he-will-have-been-drinking-all-day)

Comment: No, it does not. There is no reference to the past here.

Comment: Of course there is  - the eclipse was 'last night' and B speculates on what many people were probably doing at the time.

Comment: I mean there is no reference to the past in your example.

Comment: It's not an example, it's a link to an earlier question on the same topic. The speaker supposes that the person in question _has been drinking_ all day.

Comment: Sorry I don't get how the link you posted is similar to my example which is about a finished event in the past. And I have never seen such use before. Otherwise would have never asked.

Comment: It makes no difference whether the event had a definite finish time or not. Most people _were probably_ watching TV at the time of the eclipse. The alcoholic _was probably_ drinking all day.

Comment: I have never had any problems understanding "Most people were probably watching TV at the time of the eclipse". But I sure was puzzled by the "Most people will have been watching TV at the time of the eclipse" use for a long time before asking. Do you think this question is just a particular case of the question you referenced and we should remove mine?

Comment: Yes, that's why I flagged it as a duplicate. As the answer says "One of [the functions of 'will'] is to express likelihood".

Comment: Well, it says it cannot be removed now.

Comment: If some more people vote to close it as a duplicate it will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

B: I suppose most people will have been watching the Eurovision Song Contest on TV when it happened. [used but not standard]

I suppose they *will be eating* dinner *now*.

I suppose they **will have been eating** dinner *since* 8 pm. [spoken in the present]

Bear in mind: in speech, yours is fine. In writing, I'd do this:

B: Most people *would have been watching* the Eurovision Song Contest on TV when it happened. [standard, in writing] because the meaning is past tense.

Compare:

- He says *he will be working* tonight when the cops *arrive.*
- He says *he would have been working* tonight when the cops *arrived.*